# output layers seem to get 'saturated' using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

Ive been trying to construct a 1-D sinusoidal form using a simple DNN (tensorflow 1.4).

```
def net(input, h_dim, out_dim, depth, activationFn):
        h = activationFn(linear(input, h_dim, 't0'))
        for d in range(depth):
           h = activationFn(linear(h, h_dim, "t{:d}".format(d+1)))

        h = linear(h, out_dim, 'tOut')

        return h
```

for some reason, output seems not to catch the 'sinus' wave, but rather get saturated and monotonic. (regardless of net depth/width/output layer type). 'linear' is a linear layer

```
tf.matmul(input,w) + b
```

activationFn is tf.LeakyReLU.

[red line is sinusoid wave, blue is net output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33K9Z.png)
any ideas why?
thanks ahead.

Comment: I have written a function approximator using low level tensorflow APIs a few months back. I just checked and it still works. I had a slightly different goal though, I wanted to illustrate that function approximators were useless outside of trained range. But inside the range it learns the sinusoid very-very closely. Here is a gist link to my notebook, hope it helps.
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ea0a4a8036fe5affa6ad8b8ee03f1f09

Comment: I think I am going to rewrite it to use higher level APIs, tf.layers and tf.estimator. If you are interested, I will post that result here as well.

Comment: Thanks, Mad Wombat, your example helped me improve my code alot. it seems that problem was with initialization where I used the default stddev. maybe rewriting your code would help other users.